# How to unlock a chart and forbid cutting it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet containing several charts & tables, the sheet is protected and all charts are locked.

I would like to make it possible for the users to copy the charts.
Either by right clicking and selecting copy or by triggering a macro at when clicking or double clicking a chart.

I've tried playing around with the locked property of a chart & the `ActiveChart.ProtectSelection` but if the chart is unlocked or selectable the users are still able to cut the chart away from the sheet.

Assigning a macro to the chart also doesn't solve the problem as I haven't found a way to find out what chart has been clicked (and if possible I would avoid having to write a separatate sub for each chart..).

I've tried using the `Chart1_BeforeDoubleClick` event but I can't get it to work (does it only work in a chart worksheet?)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a sub routine on that chart:

```
Private Sub Chart1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture
    MsgBox "Chart copied."
End Sub
```

Since you're going to use it on multiple charts, you need to identify the name of the chart first:

```
Sub Chart_Click()

    Dim chartName As String

    chartName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).CopyPicture
    MsgBox "Chart copied."

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! but in that case I will have to write a sub for each chart... I was hoping to find a common solution

Comment: Aha! I modified it a little bit so it can be assigned to other charts as well.